# How can one restrict Firebase Admin SDK to delete data from firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have firebase rules to restrict users from accessing certain part of my firebase databases, but how can I restrict the user initialized with Firebase Admin SDK to delete my firebase database nodes?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

When accessing Realtime Database using the Admin SDK, it has unrestricted access to your database by default.  Security rules don't apply.

The only way to restrict the Admin SDK is to initialize it with UID that forces it to behave as if it authenticated as user with that UID.  [This is described in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges) using `databaseAuthVariableOverride`.  There is also [another answer on SO](http://v) that describes what to do for nodejs.  If you scope access like this, your security rules will have to specifically call out that UID in the rules to limit its access.